# Como crear un limite de altura de una pagina con CSS

Tags: html, css, diseño

Estoy haciendo unas practicas de una pagina Web. Mi problema es que quiero delimitar una altura máxima de mi pagina pero no encuentro la manera, leí que podía ser con max-height pero no me respeta y cuando se acaban mis elementos me sigue dejando mucho espacio hacia abajo.

Hasta el final de mi ultimo elemento que esta en la imagen que es 'agua mineral' se crea mucho espacio que no ocupo por lo que por eso quiero delimitar un alto maximo.

----HTML----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js">
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="referenceFirebase.js"></script>
<script src="productos.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosMenuNuevo.css">
<title> Productos</title>
</head>


<body onload="load();">

 <h1 class="menu">Menú</h1>
 <h3 class="categoriaBebidas"> BEBIDAS</h3>
 <h3 class="categoriaComida"> ALIMENTOS</h3>

 <div class="bebidas" id="cajaBebidas"></div>

<div class="comida" id="cajaComida"></div>



</body>

</html>



    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif');


* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 0;
 }

body {

background: #4B5050;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
width: 330px;
background-image: url("fondo.jpg");
}
```

[image: Disculpen que haya tenido que agregar la imagen asi pero no encontraba como ejemplificar]

Comment: ¿Y  qué debería mostrar en ese espacio que sobra?

Comment: Nada, al contrario quisiera quitar todo ese espacio sobrante.

Comment: Ahora mismo tienes que el body ocupa 10px de altura máxima. La verdad que me extraña bastante que ese CSS sea el mismo que muestras en la imagen..

Comment: De hecho si lo quito no pasa nada, sigue manteniendo el mismo espacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si estas colocando todo el CSS y **nos falta conocer el html**, pero creo que el problema radica en que estas usando el `body` como fondo, ya que aunque le pongas un límite (que en realidad se cumple) lo cierto es que visualmente este siempre ocupa el 100% del alto del viewport. Mira por ejemplo, basta con ponerle un borde y te darás cuenta de lo que digo.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }

body {

background: #4B5050;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
width: 330px;
height: 10px;
border: solid red 10px;
background-image: url("http://picsum.photos/250/200");
}
```

Es una característica de `body`, sin embargo, y no es una obligación, una mejor práctica es hacerlo vía **contenedor principal** y a este agregarle el fondo, de esta manera:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }

body {
}

.principal-container{
  background: #4B5050;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 330px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid red 10px;
  background-image: url("http://picsum.photos/250/200");
}
```

```html
<div class="principal-container"></div>
```

Ojo! esto solo afectará a la imagen de fondo, los elementos que sobresalgan el tamaño máximo del altura del body, van a seguir apareciendo, para que no sobresalga visualmente deberás agregar como te han recomendado un `overflow: hidden;` al contenedor.

Ahora, probablemente pienses que es un error o comportamiento extraño, lo cierto es que no, fue pensado precisamente para que eso fuese lo que tuviese que pasar, ya que por lo general cuando se aplica una imagen o color de fondo al body, siendo la penúltima etiqueta ancestro posible (la 1ra es la etiqueta `html`)  fue pensado que este fondo debería siempre verse como fondo de todo el documento.

Mis fuentes [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/sections.html#the-body-element) & [W3](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element).

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Aunque me costo entender lo que dices analizándolo bien tienes toda la razón. Anexo el html pero no tengo tantos elementos porque casi todos los estoy creando desde Javascript por lo que tal vez esa sea la razon por la que se esta comportanto asi.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ocupar la propiedad `overflow` con valor `hidden` que se ocupa para ocultar tu scroll cuando determinas un alto maximo

> También puedes ocupar `overflow-x` o `overflow-y`

```css
body {
  background-image: url("fondo.jpg");
  background: #4B5050;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;  
  max-height: 10px;
  width: 330px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: gracias por contestar. Te comento rápidamente que hacia arriba tengo un menú entonces tengo que ocupar el scroll para bajar por el menú, pero hasta el final de mi ultimo elemento que esta en la imagen que es  'agua mineral' se crea mucho espacio que no ocupo por lo que por eso quiero delimitar un alto maximo.

Comment: Si te sirve la respuesta no olvides de marcar con el chek parea que otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema sepan que es la respuesta que buscan

Comment: esas anotaciones la deberías dar a conocer al formular tu pregunta para poderte entender mejor.